# Pandas: join 'on' failing

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames, df1:

```
        ID     value 1
0      5      162
1      7      185
2      11     156
```

and df2:

```
        ID     Comment
1      5      
2      7      Yes!
6      11
```

... which I want to join using `ID`, with a result that looks like this:

```
ID     value 1     Comment
5      162
7      185         Yes!
11     156
```

The real DataFrames are much larger and contain more columns, and I essentially want to add the `Comment` column from `df2` to `df1`. I tried using

```
df1 = df1.join(df2['Comment'], on='ID')
```

... but that only gets me a new empty `Comment` column in df1, like .join somehow fails to use the `ID` column as the index. I have also tried

```
df1 = df1.join(df2['Comment'])
```

... but that uses the default indexes, which don't match between the two DataFrames (they also have different lengths), giving me a `Comment` value on the wrong place.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a merge to achieve what you want:

```
In [30]:

df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
Out[30]:
   ID  value1 Comment
0   5     162    None
1   7     185    Yes!
2  11     156    None

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

The problem with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is that by default it performs a left index join, because your dataframes do not have a common index values that match then your comment column ends up being empty

**EDIT**

Following on from the comments, if you want to retain all values in `df1` and add just the comments that are not empty and have ID's that exist in `df1` then you can perform a `left` merge:

```
df1.merge(df2.dropna( subset=['Comment']), on='ID', how='left')
```

This will drop any rows with empty comments, use the ID column to merge both `df1` and `df2` to but perform a `left` merge so retains all values on left hand side but will merge comments that match `ID` column, the default is `inner` which retains `ID`s that are in both left and right dfs.

Further information on [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and further [examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/merging.html).

Comment: That does work, but what if df2 contains a lot more values that, for this operation, I'm not interested in? It gives the comment on the correct ID, but it also adds a lot of redundant duplicate rows... I only want to add the Comment column on the single entry.

Comment: So you only want values where `Comment` is not `None`? You can drop them after or during the merge: `df1.merge(df2.dropna( subset=['Comment']), on='ID')` If this is what you want then I will update my answer

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but if I use that the resulting `df1` contains only one row, due to the merging...

Comment: @ErikF. I'm a little confused here you only want comments that are not empty and add them to df1, I don't see how you can do this as it's counter-intuitive, are you wanting `df1.merge(df2.dropna( subset=['Comment']), on='ID', how='left')`?

Comment: Sorry, if I'm being obtuse, I'm still somewhat new at this. I basically have df1 and df2 and I want the result that I showed in the post and figured `.join` would be the thing to use. Having the whole Comment column with both empty and non-empty is fine, but I don't want to duplicate rows that seems to give with your original solution.

Comment: @ErikF. merge by default will perform an `inner` merge, this means that it will give a result where the ID is in both left and right dataframes, if you want to retain all values on the left then perform a 'left' merge, if you want a combination of both sides then perform an 'outer' merge. So which is it you want?